# Implementation of a minigame inside a first person game - UE4

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I was searching for a form to develop a minigame inside a first-person game. The minigame itself is something that I´ve already got, but I don't know how to implement it. I found a perfect example of what I want to do but I can´t find how.
I´ll link the video that has the example.

[Example of minigame implementation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FcxA_xYnHZ8&feature=youtu.be&t=9m20s)

I thought about using "open level" commands but when I return from the minigame the first-person level is reloaded and it lost everything that the player previously made.

Comment: The best thing to do is probably to add the minigame as a sublevel, stream it in when the player gets close, and make it visible when it's supposed to activate.

Comment: Thanks man, that really worked very well